# Convert Datetime.Date to DT Format Int

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

Im trying to convert the following datetime.date field into a dt format off my django form to send to Microsoft API.  Here is my code.

```
form = NewEventRequestViewForm(instance = record_id)
obj = form.save(commit= False)  
print(obj.date)
2020-5-12
new_event.start = dt.datetime(obj.date)   <--- this created an error because its not in int form.
```

How do I convert this so this is the format new_event.start = dt.datetime(2020, 5 , 12)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the type of `obj.date` ?

Comment: obj.date is my date field in django. So if you set obj = form.save it makes it a dictionary of all the fields in that form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe:

```
import datetime
new_event.start = datetime.strptime(str(obj.date) , "%Y-%m-%d" )
```

Comment: That worked but its converting it to this date when i do a print 2020-01-24 00:05:00-05:00